# Magento2: Insert data into a custom table on product creation?

Tags: magento2, custom, products

How to insert data into a custom table on product creation in Magento2

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you created table, models etc ?

Comment: Can you show what data you want to store after product creation ?

Comment: @Pawan yes I have created table and model.

Comment: @Msquare I want to store userid, merchantid, productid, and product details.

Comment: You should used plugin for achieve this data.

Comment: What plugin or event should I use to achieve this?

Comment: use `catalog_product_save_after` observer, get all product data and save in your custom table

Comment: did it worked with observer ?

Comment: I am just trying to work with observer.

Comment: Using obsever  'obsever catalog_product_save_after' is the better solution for that